# ADTF SDK: import manifest AND handle it

Tags: automation, sdk, adtf, adtf3

I'm trying to run a **full ADTF configuration** from my own **C++ command-line application** using the **ADTF SDK**. ADTF version: **2.9.1** (pretty old).

Here's what I have (want) to do:

1. **Load manifest** file
2. **Load globals-xml**
3. **Load config-xml**

**2 & 3 are done**, using the **session-manager** service - see **ISessionManager** interface: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v2/adtf_sdk_html_docs/classadtf_1_1_i_session_manager.html , functions **LoadGlobalsFromFile** & **LoadConfigFromFile**.

The problem is that **I don't know how to do point 1**: currently, instead of loading a manifest, I manually load the list of services myself using **_runtime->RegisterPlugin**, **_runtime->CreateInstance** and **_runtime->RegisterObject**.

What I've managed to do is to load only the **namespace service** and use the **INamespace** interface which has a method for loading manifest files: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v2/adtf_sdk_html_docs/classadtf_1_1_i_namespace.html - see **ImportFile** with ui32ImportFlags = **CF_IMPORT_MANIFEST**.

But **this only loads the manifest settings into the namespace**, it doesn't actually instantiate the services. I could do it manually, by:

1. Do **_runtime->RegisterPlugin** for every **url** under
   **root/plugins/** in the namespace
2. Do **_runtime->CreateInstance** for every **objectid** under
   **root/services/** in the namespace

But I want this to be more **robust** and I'm hoping there's already **a service that handles the populated namespace subsequently** and does these actions. **Is there such a service?**

Note: if you know how this could be done in **ADTF3** that might **also be of help** for me, so don't hesitate to answer/comment

**UPDATE**

See "Flow of the system" on this page: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v2/adtf_sdk_html_docs/page_service_layer.html

Apparently the **runtime instance itself handles the manifest** file (see run-levels shutdown & kernel) but I don't know how I'm supposed to tell it where it is.

I've tried setting the **command-line arguments** to be **count = 2** and the **2nd = manifest file path** when instantiating **cRuntime**. **It doesn't work :)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, not exactly what I expected though. I tried debugging adtf_runtime.exe to find out what **arguments** it passes to **cRuntime**.

The result is indeed similar to what I've suspected (and actually tried):

- arg1 = adtf_runtime.exe (**argv[0] in adtf_runtime**)
- arg2 = **full path to manifest file** (e.g. $(ADTF_DIR)\bin\adtf_devenv.manifest)
- arg3 = **basename of manifest file, without extension** (e.g. "adtf_devenv")

While this **suggested** that **cRuntime** indeed is responsible with **loading and handling the manifest**, it turned out to be **NOT quite so**, passing the same arguments to it did not do the job. The answer came when I noticed that **adtf_runtime.exe** was actually using an extension of **cRuntime** called **cRuntimeEx** which is **NOT** part of the **SDK** (at least I haven't found it).

This class **IS** among the **exported symbols** of the **ADTF SDK library**, i.e. a "**dumpbin /symbols adtfsdk_290.lib**" renders at some point:

> public: __cdecl adtf::cRuntimeEx::cRuntimeEx(int,char const * *
>   const,class ucom::IException * *)

but it is **NOT part of the SDK** (you won't find a header file defining it).

**Among its methods** you'll also find this:

> protected: long __cdecl adtf::cRuntimeEx::LoadManifest(class adtf_util::cString const &,class std::set,class std::allocator > *,class ucom::IException * *)

Voila. And thus, unfortunately, I cannot achieve what I wanted in a robust fashion. :)

I **ended up manually implementing** the manifest-loading logic, since **cRuntimeEx is not made available** within the SDK. Something along these lines:

1. Use a **cDOM** instance to **load the manifest file**
2. Call **FindNodes("/adtf:manifest/environment/variable")** to find the environment-variables that need to be set and set them using **"cSystem::SetEnvVariable**"
3. Call **FindNodes("/adtf:manifest/dependencies/platform")** to find library dependencies and use **cDynamicLinkage::Load** to load the libraries that target the current platform (**win32/linux**)
4. Call **FindNodes("/adtf:manifest/plugins/plugin")** to find the services to be loaded using **_runtime->RegisterPlugin** (you may also handle "**optional**" attribute)
5. Call **FindNodes("/adtf:manifest/services/service")** to find the services that need to be created using **_runtime->CreateInstance** and **_runtime->RegisterObject** (you may also handle "**optional**" attribute)
6. And, finally, call **FindNodes("/adtf:manifest/manifests/manifest")** to (recursively) **load child-manifests** (you may also handle "**optional**" attribute)

Answer (score 3):

In ADTF3 you can just use the supplied cADTFSystem class to initiate an ADTF system and then use the ISessionManager interface to load a session of your choice.

Comment: @CorneliuZuzu, the file corresponding to an ADTF2 manifest is called .adtfsystem in ADTF3. It still defines which plugins are loaded and which services are instantiated. And yes, cADTFSystem in combination with the session manager found in the adtf_core.adtfplugin supports everything you can do with the adtf_launcher executable as well. An ADTF session (.adtfsession) defines the combination of .adtfsystem, .adtfgraph and .adtfproperties files.

Comment: Ah, I understand. And what is the exact procedure? I don't see cADTFSystem to offer a method to load an .adtfsystem file either, just as the cRuntime in ADTF2 doesn't offer a method to load a manifest file. https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/adtf_html/classadtf_1_1system_1_1ant_1_1c_a_d_t_f_system.html

Comment: Create your cADTFSystem instance and call its Launch method, then retrieve the adtf::services::ISessionManager interface via the runtime. This interface offers a CreateSession(...) method.

Comment: I see, so the ISessionManager has this capability. I'm guessing the session-manager service needs to be loaded manually, as in ADTF2, yes?

Comment: Please take a look at the cADTFSystem class definition. Just pass the filename of the adtf_core.adtfplugin to it's SetADTFCorePlugin method and then call the EnableSessionManagerCreation method before you call Launch.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is start the adtf launcher with the meta files (manifest. This works for adtf 2 as well as for adtf 3. It can be done (console) application. If you also want to do a little bit more in adtf 3, you can use adtf control instead of adtf launcher with its scripting interface (see the scripts under examples)

Comment: Hi @C-3PFLO, thank you for your answer. I want to do what adtf-launcher does programatically, from my own C++ application. I need to do this because there are also some other custom things I'm trying to achieve programatically.